# Running Multiple Threads

Tags: java

I am using 1 thread for 2 tasks

1. Reading file
2. Download file

   ```
   scheduledExecutorService1 = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);
   ```

But with multiple files, there will be a delay per thread.

Using the following code causes *duplicates*:

```
scheduledExecutorService1 = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(2);
```

What will be the correct code to run with multiple threads handling delays and avoiding dulication.

Comment: If you are reading and downloading two different files, may be read and download in two different threads independent of each other?

Comment: How it is possible

Comment: @PrakashKiran could you share more code to see what "Duplicates occur" mean in your case?

Answer (score 1):

It is better to create two ExecutorService one for reading file another for downloading file.

```
       ExecutorService readService = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);

       ExecutorService downloadService = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);
```

Comment: Yes both are independent